# httpd direct based on HTTP header

Tags: apache, load-balancing, httpd.conf

I have some existing config to redirect traffic to a different service depending on the URL path, and if no path matches defaults to a "main" load balanced service

```
<Proxy balancer://main>

        BalancerMember http://main-service01:8080
        BalancerMember http://main-service02:8080
</Proxy>

ProxyPreserveHost on

ProxyPassMatch "/server.txt" !

ProxyPassMatch "^/register/(.*)$"  http://register_service/$1
ProxyPassMatch "^/login/(.*)$"  http://login_service/$1
ProxyPassMatch "^/lookup/(.*)$"  http://lookup_service/$1


ProxyPassMatch ".*" balancer://main-service nofailover=Off maxattempts=3 timeout=5
```

This works!
Now I wish to extend the functionality so if the request contains HTTP header environment = dev, the request should be directed to the dev server instead of the main server in the event the path does not match one of the other conditions

I tried adding this just above the ".*" case but did not work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:environment} dev
RewriteRule (.*) http://dev:8080/$1 [P]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above config does work but you have to remember to turn the RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteEngine on
```